Is First-Class Constraint Generator of matter Gauge Symmetry in EM example?
In EM theory, we can find first-class primary constraint,
$$\Pi^{0}(x) = 0\tag{1}$$
and first-class secondary constraint,
$$\partial_{i} \Pi^{i}(x) = 0\tag{2}$$
with Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L} = -(1/4)F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}\tag{3}$$ and $$\Pi^{\mu}(x) \equiv \partial\mathcal{L}/\partial\left(\partial_0A_{\mu}(x)\right)\tag{4}$$
and we know Lagrangian has gauge symmetry,
$$A^{\mu}(x)\rightarrow A^{\mu}(x)-\partial_{\mu}\epsilon(x)\tag{5}$$
which we can see easily that first-class constraints (1) and (2) are the generators of this gauge symmetry,
$$\epsilon(x)\left[A^{\mu}(\mathbf{x}, t), \partial_{\nu}\Pi^{\nu}(\mathbf{y},t)\right]_{\text{P}} = -\partial^{\mu}\epsilon(x)\tag{6}$$
where I've used integration by parts.
However, I don't know how to see (1) and (2) are generators of $U(1)$ symmetry, that is, if we're discussing scalar QED, we have complex scalar field $\phi$ whose gauge symmetry should be
$$\phi(x)\rightarrow\exp\left(iq\epsilon(x)\right)\,\phi(x).\tag{7}$$
But I'm not really sure how to compute the following to confirm first-class constraints are indeed generator of $U(1)$ symmetry of the matter field,
$$\epsilon(x)\left[\phi(\mathbf{x}, t), \partial_{\mu}\Pi^{\mu}(\mathbf{y}, t)\right]_{\text{P}} = \quad ?\tag{8}$$

I think you need to start from an action where $\phi$ is coupled to $A_\mu$ (ie, include the covariant derivative term $(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger D^\mu \phi$). This should modify the Gauss's law constraint so that instead of $\nabla \cdot E=0$, you get $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$, where $\rho$ is the charge density due to $\phi$. Then the modified first class Gauss's law constraint should have a non-zero commutator with $\phi$. The answer should be something like $\epsilon [\phi, C] \propto q \phi \epsilon$, since the right hand side should be the first order variation of the full transformation.

From @Andrew's comment, I know how to solve it.
In scalar QED, EM field would couple to current $J^{\mu}(x) = \phi^{\star}(x)\partial^{\mu}\phi(x) - \phi(x)\partial^{\mu}\phi^{\star}(x)$, and the first-class secondary constraint becomes,
$$\partial_{i}\Pi^{i}(x)-J^{0}(x) = 0$$
Then we inspect my problem,
$$q\epsilon(x)\left[\phi(\mathbf{x},t), \left(\partial_{i}\Pi^{i}-\phi^{\star}\pi_{\phi^{\star}}+\phi\pi_{\phi}\right)(\mathbf{y}, t)\right]_{\text{P}} = q\epsilon(x)\phi(x)$$
note that $\pi_{\phi} = \partial_{0}\phi^{\star}$
cheers!

Nice! You can accept your own answer, FYI.


The solution to OP's problem is to include a pertinent matter sector in the E&M Lagrangian (3) (in OP's case: a complex scalar $\phi$). This produces the source term in the first-class secondary constraint (2), i.e. Gauss's law $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}-\rho\approx 0$, that in turn generates the sought-for gauge transformation, cf. above comment by Andrew.

Note that there should be no time-derivatives left in the Hamiltonian formalism, so the time derivatives appearing in OP's eqs. (6) and (8) are inconsistent with a pure Hamiltonian framework.

The 2 first-class constraints $\Pi^0\approx 0$ and $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}-\rho\approx 0$ in fact generate 2 gauge transformations, cf. Ref. 1.


References:

K. Sundermeyer, Constrained Dynamics, Lecture Notes in Physics 169, 1982; chapter V p.134.

